# What does 'for' mean in 'We are done for'?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

There is an English expression **do for**, which means *to kill, to execute, to ruin, to defeat etc.* and this expression seems to always be used in passive voice: e.g.) **We are done for**.

I understand this is like an idiom, but why is the preposition **for** used? 
Most prepositions have so many meanings to them, and I would like to know what *for* in this case means.

edit: 
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/for
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for

In the definitions of the above links, which **for** do you all think the **for** in *done for* is the closest to?

edit 2:
I don't think the *for* is dangling, but I just want to know why *for* is used. Like, *for* normally means *purpose*, *cause*, or *to be given*, etc.
But the *for* in question means quite opposite.

Comment: Just guessing, but it could be a shortened form of the phrase "for good." Thus, it would read, "We are done for good." Meaning, there's no coming back from it, and it's over. I don't think the verb phrase "do for" is a thing, though, as I've not heard or read, "He will do for him" with the meaning "to kill"

Comment: Yes, it is - https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/do-for

Comment: @KateBunting Who/what are you replying to? (Your link doesn't have the word "good".)

Comment: @Keepthesemind  I was replying to Carly, who did not think 'do for' was 'a thing'.

Comment: @KateBunting Ah. Understood.

Comment: to be done for just means that you have lost something you have been trying to solve or win or gain.

Comment: We can use a different preposition in some contexts without changing the meaning at all: *I simply can't go on - I'm **done in**.* Although [strictly speaking](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/done) ***done for = doomed*** and ***done in = exhausted***, they can sometimes amount to the same thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers can you explain why in is used? What does that in mean?

Comment: ...also note usages such as [*It's all the same to me whether our Ferdinand was **done in** by a Serb or a Turk, a Catholic or a Moslem, an anarchist or a young Czech liberal,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ferdinand+was+done+in+by%22) where ***to be done in by X = to be killed by X***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Since passive voice makes sense, there should be active voice as well whether that is actually used or not. So can you say "I did in you" to mean "I killed you" ?

Comment: Yes, except the word order is different, usually: "[I did you in](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do_in)."

Comment: _Done in by_ traditionally means _Done to death_ ('done' standing-in for any method by which this outcome might be achieved). Hence is quite distinct from _done in_ (meaning exhausted).

Comment: @Jessica.D No, it would be odd indeed to use the phrase "I did you in", because it would be difficult to conduct a conversation with _you_ (_you_ being _done in_, i.e. deceased).  :(   [Although it is particularly odd how _done in_  varies in different contexts, in one meaning deceased and in another meaning merely exhausted.]

Comment: @Jessica.D : When the indirect object of a phrasal verb is a ***pronoun***, it normally goes ***between*** the two components of the phrasal verb. So putting aside the practical issue re communicating with the dead, as mentioned by Ed999 above, you could in principle say ***I did you in***. But for reasons I can't explain offhand in a comment, this doesn't apply to ***to do for X*** when used with the same *kill, or cause great harm* sense, which can only be expressed as ***I did for him***, not ***I did him for*** (where I changed the pronoun to make it a bit more credible in the real world).

Comment: @Carly I agree what ever words originally came after "for" were dropped years ago and the middle of the phrase became enough to be understood. There are many common phrase like this but I can't think of one right now

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that the rule of putting a pronoun in between is if the word is an adverb, not preposition.  "in" of "I did you in" is an adverb most likely, and therefore you can put you in between. As for "do for", I am sure it has to be "do for someone" because the word "for" does not have adverb usage, as far as I know. "For" is almost always a preposition, and so a noun must come right after. (Excluding the conjunctive usage of "for")

Comment: I believe that this is just a colloquial expression.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

"For" at this point doesn't seem to have any meaning here, although it does add a little emphasis.

Specifically, it looks to me like "done for" could be actually a variation of the even older, now-obsolete verb "fordo".

The earliest example in the OED for "done for" is from a1500:

> By thre skyllis may hit come to Why hit [sc. a stillborn child] is don for [Lansd. fordone] alsoo.
>    <sub>*Sidrak & Bokkus* (Laud)</sub>

"[Lansd. fordone]" means that in another manuscript they used "fordone" instead of "don[e] for". (Unfortunately I haven't been able to access either version.)

If you look at [this free definition for "fordo"](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED16755/track?counter=1&search_id=147748) (for Middle English, but still applicable), you'll see it is essentially a synonym for "done for". "Fordo" is ancient (first attested in English in the year c900) and apparently derives from ["Proto-Germanic *fardōną, *fradōną (“to ruin, destroy”)"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fordo).

According to the OED, the "for" prefix in "fordo" means:

> Implying destructive, painful, or prejudicial effect, as in *fordeem*, *fordo*

It's worth mentioning that the now-obsolete word ["fordeem"](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED16743/track?counter=1&search_id=153278) is a synonym because it means "to ruin or destroy", although it also means "to condemn". There are other obsolete words that also have this "for" meaning destruction prefix but I can't think of any current ones. Of course there are plenty of current verbs with other senses of the same "for" prefix: forgive, forget, forbid, etc.

Comment: If correct (and I see no reason to doubt this, given the existence of the [Dutch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verdoen#Dutch) and [German](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertun#German) cognates), this presumably means that the "for" in "fordo" / "do for" is etymologically the anglicized form of the Proto-Germanic prefix [\*_fra-_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/fra-), meaning "off" or "away". So "do for" literally means "do away". Nice.

Comment: For those seeking an example from contemporary speech, the obvious example, then, is _do away with_.

Comment: Anther examples of the "for" prefix is "forgo" (not to be confused with "forego").

Comment: Unlike @IlmariKaronen I would interpret the "for" component as "fore", as in English "before" and "afore".  So in modern terms, the speaker is so certain that the sentence object is "done" that it might as well have already happened "before" now.

Comment: @Acccumulation not to be confused with Fargo :)

Answer (score 24):

#### tl;dr - It's not the word you think it is

Short answer:  the "for" isn't a preposition, it's part of the verb "to do for", it doesn't have any meaning on its own, and the reason why that word and not another are lost in the mists of time - if there ever was a reason.

### Phrasal verbs

"To do for" is an example of what's known as a [phrasal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) in English.  The verb is **to do for**, and it's transitive (i.e., it takes a subject, so you have to say "to **do for** (object)").  This can look confusing if you try to analyse it as the construction "to **do** (X) for (Y)", but in that case the verb is simply "**do**", and "for" is acting in its normal role as preposition.

The closest synonym for "to do for" is [to doom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doom), although many of the common uses can also carry the meaning of "to kill".  "To do for" is quite informal, though - you won't see this in a coroner's report, but you will often hear people on the street using it (e.g. "It was the drink that *did for* him in the end", or "He *did for* my shin with that last tackle!").

As you note, "We are done for" is simply the [passive-voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice) version of the active sentence "(someone) has done for us", meaning that someone has doomed us to a fate, although that fate does not have to be death. It's almost a stock-phrase, and it's slightly comedic: this phrase is often uttered by villains in British comedy writing - there it is best translated as "all is lost, and we will be caught and imprisoned".

"Do for" *is* used in its active sense, but very rarely in American English. I have heard British speakers saying things like "I did for my leg last night" meaning that they've injured themselves, but it's very much informal, and it may be regional (North of England rather than South).

#### The bits don't mean anything on their own

Some advice: do not try to look for some kind of deeper meaning behind the two parts of this kind of verb. Some make sense ("take in", "drop off", "run out"), but others don't really ("do in", "let on", "give up", "turn up").  Just accept that in English, there are some verbs that are made up of a "verby" word and a "prepositiony" word that act together to create a completely new, and usually idiomatic, meaning.

( This isn't just English, by the way. German has many such idiomatic phrasal verbs such as *umbringen*. That one looks like it should mean "bring around", from "um" and "bringen", but it actually means "to kill" - however, the sentence "ich bringe die Kinder um 08:00" doesn't mean you're planning a murder!)

Here are some other common phrasal verbs of the same type as "do for":

- I **give in** : I admit defeat
- She **gave out** about... : (first meaning) She complained about...
- The bearing **gave out** : (second meaning) The bearing failed
- I **give up** : I quit
- I **did in** my knee : (informal) I damaged my knee
- I **did up** the room : I decorated the room
- She **turned up** today :  she appeared today
- She **turned down** the invitation :  she declined the invitation
- She **had** a grey dress **on** : She wore a grey dress

My personal experience (I speak British English, but work extensively with Americans) would suggest that there are more of these verbs in regular use in British English than American, but they're a common feature of English, and they're not something you can avoid.

Comment: Welcome to our site, and congratulations on an answer that meets all our expectations in terms of being *authoritative, detailed, and explaining why it is correct*. +1 is not enough ;-)

Answer (score 11):

According to Green’s Dictionary of Slang done for is the adjectival form of the phrasal verb ***do (a bad turn) for*** meaning to injure, kill. The preposition *for* would derive from the verbal form.

***[Done for](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/aeybv3y)*** adj.

(do for v./ext. of done adj.)

> 1821: 
>   without a chance, hopeless, defeated, lost, abandoned, ‘finished’.
>
> - 1843 [UK]   *‘Bill Truck’ Man o’ War’s Man - 112: He’s done for now,*

***[Do for](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/xxaegfq)*** verb:

[Do v.1 (1)/abbr. SE phr. ***do a bad turn for***

> > to beat up, to injure, to murder.
>
> - 1751    [UK]    Fielding Amelia II 70: *He said something, too, about my master [...] he said he would do for him, I am sure he said that; and other wicked, bad words, too.*

Comment: // , Why the dangling "for", though? This answer still is not direct enough to the question's intent.

Comment: @NathanBasanese -  it is from a previous expression as explained, where for was used to indicate for whom the “bad turn” was.

Comment: @NathanBasanese In the active voice (as in the Fielding quote) there must be *something* after "do", since "he would do him" seems a grammatical error compared with the correct "he would do the homework". "Fordo" may have evolved into "do for" in the a similar pattern to "without" and the Scottish "outwith" (which is often used by Scots when speaking nominally British English.)

Comment: @alephzero "He would do him" is grammatically fine. The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/56228?rskey=nJCQvU&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid) gives the following, among many definitions of _do_: "19. transitive. slang. To have sexual intercourse with. Also intransitive."

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of "done for" here cannot be found by combining meanings of "done" and "for" somehow.

> **done for**
>   *PHRASE*
>   *informal*
>   In a situation so bad that it is impossible to get out.
>   ‘if the guard sees us, we're done for’

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/done_for)

Comment: Of course the meaning can be found by combining them! As a Germanic-origin preposition, meaning 'before', _for_ combines with _done_ to mean _we are doomed_ (future tense), distinguishing _done for_ from _done in_ meaning _dead_ (past tense). The use of 'before' gives the phrase (_done for_) a meaning in the future: the death is yet to come, we are before it. The use of _in_ gives the other phrase (_done in_) its past tense: the death has occured. But Jessica is not asking what the term means, she is asking which dictionary definition, of 12 possibilities, covers it. However _none_ of them do.

Comment: @Ed999 I think the point is that you can't combine any individual meanings of *done* and *for* to arrive at the meaning of *done for*, you need to asses the meaning of the combined phrase as a whole.

Comment: Once we understand "done for", we can try "done in" and "done up".

Comment: @GEdgar - and explain why "done down" is not the opposite of "done up" :)

Comment: @Ed999 "For" and "fore" are differnt words.

Comment: @Nuclear Wang : It is important to remember that, in English, a phrase can _only_ be understood by combining the meanings of the words contained in it.

Comment: @Acccumulation : I didn't mention _fore_. But if you meant to imply that _for_ is not the root of _before_ then you need to think again. 'For' is an Anglo-Saxon preposition meaning 'before'. Its ultimate origin is a Greek word,  pró, meaning 'before or ahead [of]'. Phrases which are idiomatic tend to yield their meaning only in their (deep) origin. The _important_ point to note is the distinction I have made between the _future_ tense and the _past_ tense, in comparing _done for_ with _done in_. Their meaning is identical, except that one refers to a past death and the other to a future death.

Comment: I fancy a list can clarify this question. The following phrases can all mean _killed_ or _dead_ (varying only as to whether this has already occurred or is yet to come): _done in_, _done for_, _done to death_, _done away with_. There may well be others, but these are the four that come most readily to mind. I suspect that 'for' in _done for_ most readily equates to _with_, as in _done for (him)_ = _done away with (him)_. It is essential to remember that a verb takes a subject, always, and that _to do for_ is meaningless, and the correct phrase is _to do for him_.

Comment: @Ed999 "It is important to remember that, in English, a phrase can only be understood by combining the meanings of the words contained in it." There is a difference between a phrase in which the meaning is transparent from the individual meanings put together, and one which has a meaning in addition to that.

Comment: @Acccumulation : But not in the case of Anglo-Saxon words, because they have been around for more than a thousand years. A new phrase can be invented, to describe a new technology; but when it comes to long established words their meaning is, by definition, long established. _Death_ is a pretty long established concept, pretty basic and fundamental as a concept, and pretty familiar to the Anglo Saxons: we can reasonably expect to find the meaning of such ancient concepts in the words themselves.

Answer (score 3):

The **for** in **to do for** is acting as part of a phrasal verb, not a separate preposition.

English has the concept of phrasal verbs, which is taking a verb and combining it with an adverb or a preposition to create a new verb. This new verb loses the meanings of its individual parts and takes on a brand new meaning of its own.

A simple example is the verb **to pick up**. Compare the following sentences.

1. Did you pick this ball?
2. Did you pick up this ball?

The first sentence has a clearly different meaning from the second.

Your example works the same way. The verb **to do** is clearly different from the verb **to do for**. The second sentence may sound weird because of the archaic nature of that form, but it's basically the same as above.

1. Did you do her?
2. Did you do for her?

Again, the first sentence has a clearly different meaning from the second.

To sum up, the **for** in your example does not have a separate and distinct meaning. Instead, it changes the the verb **to do** to a different verb **to do for** that as a whole has its own meaning.

A more thorough explanation and several other examples of phrasal verbs, may be found here: https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs.htm

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This post shows promise as a good answer, but how do I know that you haven't made up "satellite verb" or that the expression exists but you've used it incorrectly? The solution is to cite an authoritative reference (preferably with a hyperlink). If you [edit] your post to provide this detail, I'll happily upvote you. For further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: It's a nice idea, but it looks like you've actually illustrated that "to do for" and "to pick up" behave very differently. The third example for "to do for", "Did you do her for?", is ungrammatical, in contrast to "Did you pick this ball up?" which is fine. (The second example, "Did you do for her?", is an unlikely thing to say, but perfectly grammatical.)

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial usage, "to do for someone" can mean "to perform a service for" them, especially as an actual servant.

If the service was done in the past, you could say "Someone *is one who has been done for*," which can be shortened to "Someone *is done for*."

If the service hasn't been performed yet but is considered inevitable, the person is "*as good as done for* or simply *done for*.

In your question, "to do for someone" is ironic. The "service" to be performed is to kill them or thwart their intentions and it's definitely (in the speaker's opinion) going to happen. "He doesn't know it yet, but he's a walking dead man."

In any case, "someone" is the implied object of the preposition "for." No mystery there.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic expressions "done for" means finished in the sense of defeated or killed and the precise meaning  depends on the context. Idiomatic expressions in English cannot be interpreted or explained grammatically. The preposition "for" usually takes an object but in this case the expression is a synonym. I have never heard it used in another context such for example in the sentence "Bill did for him" or "Team A did for team B". "Done for" is a colloquialism.

Answer (score 0):

Some food for thought of where this *might* come from

Done is the past form of do

> Middle English do, first person singular of Old English don "make,
> act, perform, cause; to put, to place," from West Germanic *don (cf.
> Old Saxon duan , Old Frisian dua , Dutch doen , Old High German tuon ,
> German tun ), from PIE root *dhe- "to put, place, do, make" (see
> factitious).
>
> - https://www.dictionary.com/browse/do

While for as a prefix has the meaning

> a prefix meaning “away,” “off,” “to the uttermost,” “extremely,”
> “wrongly,” or imparting a negative or privative force, occurring in
> verbs and nouns formed from verbs of Old or Middle English origin,
> many of which are now obsolete or archaic:
>
> - https://www.dictionary.com/browse/for?s=t

So from this, the rough translation of "done for" to "have been made away" may be related or have come from it's old-english/germanic roots.

Answer (score -1):

To "do" is to make death certain.

So to "do for" somebody, is to make death certain, *for them*.

So it's the meaning "pertaining to, or affecting".

Answer (score -2):

The O.E.D. gives 12 definitions of the word '*for*' in the link you posted (the American dictionary page linked to gives many more, but I lost the will to live after the first three dozen, so let's just stick to the O.E.D. *for* now).

The answer is easy: **none** of the 12 definitions listed is appropriate for the word '*for*' in the context you've cited ('*done for*').

The O.E.D. is mostly only listing definitions of the word that fulfill some kind of *counting* function ('*for* 300 yards', '*for* 12 years', '*for* £1.20', '*for* the 3rd time', '2 bottles *for* your 1') or some form of possession (it lists objects, persons and feelings *belonging* to someone: 'you', 'Napoleon', 'everyone', 'the department', 'the Open University', 'her family').

Significantly, it gives a dozen definitions - all of which have some merit as independent, separate meanings of the word, in various contexts.

The significance, to my mind, is that there are so *many* definitions: perhaps more than for any other word in the dictionary. And that, even so, the list given does not cover the usage you are citing (in '*done for*').

This suggests, to me, that the word '*for*', by reason of its extreme antiquity, deriving from the Anglo-Saxon roots of the English language (reference has been made to it being used in c.900 AD), only has a meaning *in context*. Or perhaps one should say, it has so many meanings - due to its antiquity - because it has acquired its meaning from its context (unlike most words, which can generally be understood apart from any context).

Short words of Anglo-Saxon origin (for, of, at) tend to be inordinately flexible in meaning and usage. It suggests that these are words which the language built up around. They have no invariant meaning, and only acquire meaning from the context. There is, accordingly, more truth than you suspected in your remark that 'most prepositions have so many meanings'.

Most words have multiple meanings, and those which have been around the longest have acquired the most. No word ever came 'pre-defined', all words originally acquired their meaning from their context. But there are few words you could have chosen which would have made that point more clearly than this one.

In the context you've specified, the word '*for*' can only mean *doomed*. It can't possibly mean anything else. Yet the O.E.D. gives it 12 different meanings, in 12 different contexts, none of them remotely similar to this. The implication is that one could go on, indefinitely, citing examples of this word in different contexts. The O.E.D. doesn't attempt that. Dictionaries have limitations. Languages don't.

Comment: The dictionary you're talking about is probably "Oxford Dictionaries", not the [OED](http://www.oed.com), which is a completely different dictionary with a completely different purpose (history).

Comment: I mean the link Jessica posted on her question, but checking in my own copy of the _Concise O.E.D._ it gives 11 definitions under 'preposition' and 2 under 'conjunction'. And under 'origin' it specifies _(probably) a reduction of a Germanic preposition meaning ‘before’ (in place or time)_.

Comment: So, can this answer be summarized as: the question posed by the OP is unanswerable?

Comment: @jsw29 : No, the _correct_ answer to the o/p's question (and in fact the answer I _have_ given) is that the phrase in question is not defined in the O.E.D., nor in the online dictionary which Laurel refers to.

Comment: Is the _meaning_ of the term undefinable? I think not. The clearest meaning of _done for_ (the future tense of _done in_), really simply meaning - in both cases - _dead_, is (in its literal meaning) _do (done) away with_, from _do_ (which is clear enough) + _away_ (one of the original meanings of 'for' in Old English).

Answer (score -2):

The word **"for"** in this example is acting a phrasal verb.

A phrasal verb is a combination of words (usually a verb and a particle, such as a verb + an adverb or a verb + a preposition).

Example:

> Ashley is applying **for** university this summer.

More on the subject and detailed examples:

https://www.needgrammar.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs-types-with-examples.html

Comment: How does this apply to the example of "We are done for" from the question?